# SSRS 2005 Report Model Filter Named Query on Global UserID

Tags: reporting-services, model, reportingservices-2005, report

Is it possible to filter a named query in a reporting services data source view on the global user ID?

I would like to do something like `select UserName, ContactNumber, Email from Users WHERE (Users.UserName = User!UserID)` so that it returns the name and contact details of the user running the report.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for can be achieved by adding a filter attribute to the relevant entity in the report model. I eventually stumbled on a tutorial on MSDN which details a similar issue [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365305%28SQL.90%29.aspx).